# symfony 2.8: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() into Constraints/FormValidator

Tags: php, forms, symfony, constraints, embed

Using silex 2.0 and symfony 2.8 form component (not sf2 full stack), I have a form with several fields and an embed form.

When submitting the form, I got an error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Validator/Constraints/FormValidator.php on line 66
```

No constraints have been set to any fields and form however, in FormValidator.php, when executing `$config->getOption('constraints')`, it returns an **empty array for fields** but **`NULL` for the embed form**.

Should the constraints also be set as empty array for embed form? If we have to set it manually, where should I do it?

Here is the code:

```
class DebugPreviewChannelForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $formFactory)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }

    public function build(array $data, array $apps)
    {
          $builder = $this->formFactory->createBuilder(FormType::class, $data);

          $builder->add(
            'applicationId',
            ChoiceType::class,
            [
                'choices' => $apps,
                'label' => 'Application',
                'choices_as_values' => true,
            ]
         )
         ->add('user', UserType::class);

         return $builder->getForm();
    }
}

class UserType extends FormType implements DataMapperInterface
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
        $builder
            ->setCompound(true)
            ->setDataMapper($this)
            ->add(
                'hash',
                TextType::class,
                ['required' => false]
            );
    }
}
```

If I remove `->add('user', UserType::class)`, it works perfectly.

Comment: is the form representing a one to many relationship? sharing your code would speed this up

Comment: it is one to one relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work. I just changed implementation of userType class.

source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html

```
class UserType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add(
            'hash',
            TextType::class,
            ['required' => false]
        );
    }
}
```